# Reading from textbox when button is pushed in android

Tags: java, android, button, textedit

I'm trying to retrieve the TextBox value when I press the button, but it does not work. Here is my code. Any idea?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.httpxml);
    httpstuff  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.http);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.shoppingprice);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                //shoppingapi price =  new shoppingapi();
                et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
                txt=et.getText().toString();

            }

        });


   new Read().execute("displayprice");
}

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public JSONObject productprice(String productname) throws ClientProtocolException,IOException,JSONException
{

    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(productname);
    url.append("&searchType=keyword&contentType=json");

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());

    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    Log.d("Price", "asdasd");

    if(status == 200){
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
         jObj = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONObject jsonData = jObj.getJSONObject("mercadoresult");
        JSONObject jsonProducts = jsonData.getJSONObject("products");
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonProducts.getJSONArray("product");
        jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(1);

        jObj = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(0);

        return jObj;
        }
    else
    {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return null;    

  }
}

public class Read extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>
{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            json = productprice(txt); 

            return json.getString("displayprice");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onPostExecute(result);

        //httpstuff.setText("The price of the Product is ");
        httpstuff.setText(result);
        httpstuff.setText(txt);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

It shows no error but it shows `txt` value as blank

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: You've retrieved the text and stored it in the `txt` variable. But you're not doing anything with this `txt` variable.

Comment: in other section i tried to display it shows blank

Comment: You mean pressed like touch or clicked (I have seen people meaning  touch instead of click).

Comment: no, no error but when later in code i try to display txt is blank

Comment: no click the button, yet still shows blank

Comment: show us how you have tried in your code

Comment: @Karlee B post the complete code here.

Comment: how can i add? it keeps saying you put too much code

Comment: you can add meaning full code here.

Comment: just updated the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are calling this line

```
new Read().execute("displayprice");
```

in onCreate

Where as txt value is changing when you click on button.

So you are accessing `txt` value before assigning it. if you want to use the value change like this and try like this

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

            et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
            txt=et.getText().toString();

            new Read().execute("displayprice");

        }

    });
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU... i moved the Read to on click..problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Reference it outside `Button` click.

```
 et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Access directly inside `AsynTask` shown below

```
public class Read extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>
{
```

***`String txt = et.getText().toString();`***

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {

        json = productprice(txt); 

        return json.getString("displayprice");

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onPostExecute(result);

    //httpstuff.setText("The price of the Product is ");
    httpstuff.setText(result);
    httpstuff.setText(txt);
}
 }
```